# Resolving a Promise that calls own function

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

if I call this function, it doesn't seem to work.  what it's doing is just waiting for global variable "window.AppApi" to be initialized before doing things

i feel like maybe it's because i'm calling the function again in the time out?  is there something I'm missing to make this work?  if it's not possible what would be a good alternative..

```
initializeApp()
  .then(( result ) => {
    console.log( 'it worked!' );  // does not go here
  });


export const initializeApp = () => {
  return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    // wait for App API to be initialized
    if ( window.AppApi ) {
      console.log( 'App initialized.' );
      resolve( true );
    }
    else {
      console.log( 'waiting for App to initialize...' );
      setTimeout( () => initializeApp(), 250 );
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, make the code that sets that give you a callback or promise.

Comment: `window.AppApi` seems to be false all the time so your promise never gets resolved

Comment: Is AppApi ever resolving to something truthy, eg. after some time when you try to debug it?

Comment: If your `if` is false in the first call, how do you expect the promise to ever be resolved?

Comment: @messerbill and Luke Gmys:  window.AppApi definitely does turn into an object ( true ).  for sure, it just takes a few seconds

Comment: @SLaks that's what I'm trying to do.. make a promise so that it returns true once the variable is initialized

Comment: @user1189352: No; change the code that initializes the value to do that for you instead of checking periodically.

Comment: @SLaks per your second comment.. that's why i'm having the time out to call the function again every 250 ms so that once window.AppApi does turn into an object ( true ), it will resolve

Comment: @SLaks i can't.. it's an external API from other developers and this is how they instructed me to use it....

Comment: @user1189352: No; that makes and ignores another promise.  It doesn't affect your original promise at all.

Comment: @SLaks okay so it's just making new promises every time... gotcha.  so that's why this doesn't work.

Comment: You can do it, but better do what SLaks says.

Comment: @user1189352 due to creating a new instance on each call this will never succeed `new Promise()` - the `new` keyword will instanciate a new instance

Comment: gotcha.  okay i understand now why it's not working.  thx guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically you can do it even without dirty timeouts with old good Object.defineProperty setter:

```js
const initializeApp = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (window.AppApi) {
      resolve(true);
      return;
    }

    Object.defineProperty(window, 'AppApi', {
      set (value) {
        console.log('App initialized.');
        resolve(true);
        return value
      }
    })
  });
};

initializeApp()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log('it worked!'); // does not go here
  });

setTimeout(() => {
  window.AppApi = { test: 123 }
}, 2000)
```

Comment: I would do one initial check if `window.AppApi` is set. That would make the code more reliable, for the case that the script which calls `initializeApp` is executed after the script that sets the `AppApi`.

Comment: Ah you beat me... should I just delete mine? I think my approach was a bit more thorough than yours

Comment: oh wow.............. i like that alot.  give me a few minutes to try this.  i always felt dirty with that timeout thing...

Comment: I added some explanation in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48569963/1541563) for how this works

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the `setTimeout( () => initializeApp(), 250 )` will create a new Promise that is not used anywhere, and the first Promise that is created - and which is the only relevant for your first code block - will only be resolve if `window.AppApi` is set before the first call of `initializeApp`.

You would have to write somethign like this:

```
export const initializeApp = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      // an "inner" function that creates a closure over resolve
      // and which does the check if window.AppApi is set
      function checkIfApiLoaded() {
        if (window.AppApi) {
          console.log('App initialized.');
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          console.log('waiting for App to initialize...');

          // if window.AppApi was not set call checkIfApiLoaded with a delay,
          // because of the closure it will still know the 'resolve' function
          setTimeout(checkIfApiLoaded, 250);
        }
      }

      // initially call this inner function
      checkIfApiLoaded()
    });
```

Comment: @user1189352 Please see dsfq's and my answer, which are much more ideal for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of polling for this value, you could define it as a getter that resolves the promise:

```js
const initializeApp = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  const { AppApi } = window;
  if (AppApi) return resolve(AppApi);
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'AppApi', {
    get () { return AppApi; },
    set (value) {
      console.log('App initialized.');
      Object.defineProperty(window, 'AppApi', {
        value,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true
      });
      resolve(value);
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
  });
});

initializeApp().then(AppApi => {
  console.log(AppApi);
});

setTimeout(() => window.AppApi = { test: 123 }, 1000);
```

This uses [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to create a property accessor that resolves the promise immediately when the API is flagged as ready. This also has the added benefit of resolving with the value of `AppApi` so if it's a namespace you'll have it available as the first argument of the callback function for `.then()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that your `initializeApp` function creates a new promise each time it's called. So when it's called recursively, the original promise is lost and will never resolve. Instead, put the recursive part into its own sub-function, and call that recursively:

```js
const initializeApp = () => {
  const resolver = (res) => {
    if (window.AppApi) {
      res(true);
    } else {
      setTimeout(resolver, 250, res);
    }
  }

  return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    resolver(resolve)
  });
};

initializeApp().then(( result ) => {
  console.log( 'it worked!' );
});

setTimeout(() => { console.log("Setting api"); window.AppApi = {} }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `window.AppApi` is a value that is available in the future you may think of an object that represents that.....

A promise.

If `window.AppApi` is set to promise of `AppApi` then when you want to use it you can do:

```
window.AppApi.then(...
```

But in order to do that you should not show `initializeApp` but the code that set AppApi and how you do that. Because it seems that `initializeApp` solves a problem (quite elegantly in some answers) that should not exist in the first place.